# Generating a matrix with elements equal to the row/column

Tags: r, matrix

I recall a function in (base?) R that can generate a matrix that looks like:

```
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Dim = c(5L, 4L))
```

Displayed as:

```
>
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5    5
```

Or also the column form:

```
>
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    1    2    3    4
 [3,]    1    2    3    4
 [4,]    1    2    3    4
 [5,]    1    2    3    4
```

But I've completely forgotten what the command was, or even what to search for... can someone please remind me.

And generally the functions to generate matrices, like diag() for example, other than using matrix().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`row()` and `col()` take a matrix and return a new one of the same shape with the structure you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two lines of code that create both matrices you wrote, I am not sure if you are looking for something more general though.

```
matrix(rep(1:5,4),ncol=4)
matrix(rep(1:4,5),ncol=4,byrow=T)
```

Comment: I just reread your question.. you are opposed to using the matrix() function?

Comment: Not opposed to matrix, I just had this vague memory there was a base R function that did this - and @Neal Fultz got it: row() and col().